# Tratar aplicação NodeJS para quando crashar, o servidor restartar sozinho

Tags: javascript, node.js

Eu tenho uma aplicação NodeJS que quando crasha com algum erro na controller o servidor para e diz que está esperando arrumar o erro para poder reiniciar a aplicação. Como faço para ele restartar novamente após algum erro inesperado?

Comment: Não seria melhor você colocar um event listener no seu `process` do tipo `uncaughtException`? Assim toda exceção não capturada por um bloco try/catch será capturada pelo event listener, seu aplicativo não irá quebrar e você não precisará reiniciar todo o processo.

Comment: Então, mas o certo é realmente crashar o servidor, assim você corrige o problema com a máxima urgência

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal é que, enquando seu projeto está sendo desenvolvido, você detecte todas as exceções relevantes ao seu sistema e as trate para evitar que o processo morra por erros bobos.

Mas, erros inesperados podem acontecer em produção. Para que seu sistema não fique fora do ar, você pode usar um gerenciador de processos para monitorá-lo. Existem alguns feitos em node mesmo como o [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) e [forever](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever), e outros como o [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/).